# slightly off tree addition python

Tags: python

I am solving a problem for [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net) and this code worked for the largest path-sum in a tree with 15 levels. Now I am on a problem with 100 levels and my code seems to return an answer that is off by 9. I am not putting the tree into here because the problem seems to strictly be in the code. Can anyone help?

```
def compressLines(n):
    start = time.time()
    t = n
    while t != 0:
        p = (r[t-1].split())
        s = (r[t].split())
        g = []
        for i in range(0,len(p)):
            f = int(p[i]) + int(s[i])
            u = int(p[i]) + int(s[i+1])
            if f > u:
                p[i] = f
            if f < u:
                p[i] = u
        del r[-2:]
        string = ""
        for i in p:
            string+=(" "+str(i))
        r.append(string)        
        t = t-1
    print r, "solved in", time.time() - start, "seconds"
```

This gives me an answer (  [' 7264'] solved in 0.0369999408722 seconds  ), when the right answer is 7273.

To make the code easier to read I defined "p" as the second to last row and "s" as the last row for each time the code runs itself. What the code essentially does is compress the final row into the one above it yielding the greatest sum in each case, stopping once it has reached the final answer. Can anyone spot the problem?

Comment: I don't think this question is clear. Could you provide a link to the Project Euler problem?

Comment: I would also suggest putting the tree here. Not the whole one hundred levels, of course, but a representative sample of at least how you are storing it would be nice

Comment: to the point made by @Two-BitAlchemist use some pastebin service.

Comment: Additionally, just so you know, you almost never need `for i in range(len(x))`. Just use [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Comment: ok, i got the answer but i will definitely remember all that should i have a question in the future. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You don't consider the case that both paths have equal weight:

```
        if f > u:
            p[i] = f
        if f < u:
            p[i] = u
```

When `f == u` you don't update `p[i]`.